# Unable to run Xcode 6.3.2 on 10.11 Beta 2

Tags: xcode6.3, xcode7, ios9, xcode6.3.2, osx-elcapitan

I installed the second Beta of 10.11 and Xcode 6.3.2 has stopped running.

The error is:

In order to open "Xcode", you need to update to the latest version.

The version of Xcode installed on this Mac is not compatible with OS X El Capitan.  You have "Xcode" 6.3.2.  Download version 6.3.2 for free from the Mac App Store.

Comment: it will be OK if you upgrade to beta4

Answer (score 2):

It runs if you open it via the Terminal.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Thanks to [the poster at developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6653) who had the information.

Answer (score 0):

you can download Xcode-Launcher script to load xcode.
https://github.com/zenangst/Xcode-Launcher